# How to read url byte by byte?

Tags: java, url

Hi i am trying to read a url where i am getting a string  i am printing  that   string on console  but i want to read that url as a byte by byte  which i am  not getting  how can i  read

Here is my **ReadTextFromURL**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadTextFromURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandim/MarketWise?m=agra");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bais = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            int lin;
            while ((lin = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.println(lin);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**desired output**

```
धान~1325|चावल~2050|ज्वर~920|जौ~810|मकई~1280|गेहूँ~1420|जो~1050|बेजर~-|जय~800
```

**getting output**

```
2343
2366
2344
126
49
51
50
53
124
2330
2366
2357
2354
126
50
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your current output?

Comment: expected out  put is read string  byte by byte

Comment: Have you tried `in.read()` which returns an `int` (`byte`)?

Comment: i used in.read()  then giving error message in comparable type int:<null>

Comment: Well, `-1` is the result returned when you've exhausted the input. Not `null`. An `int` value can never be `null`.

Comment: i did so this is onlyr returning int num in out put

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want to do then. Do you mean character by character? Can you give an example of your web page contents and an example of the console output you want?

Comment: I need a while to understand what you meant was "I need to read contents of a web page one byte at a time". Writing a clear question title does help a lot.

Comment: @Duncan     i have updated my desired output and what in am  getting

Comment: @user3585120 What language is that? Using your previous code it returns wrong chars maybe because of the encoding. If it's Hindi, it is supported by utf-8

Comment: this is hindi language

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. I ran the code originally in your question and it reads the URL contents correctly. Are you saying you want your output to stop after `...|बेजर~-|जय~800`. If so, is that because you want nine pieces of data? (Assuming the pipe symbol `|` is delimiting different bits of data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read bytes, don't use `Reader`s. A `Reader` reads `char`s (not `byte`s). If you need to read `byte`s, use low-level input-output classes (`InputStream`/`OutputStream`).

Comment: could u please  little some got for clearly understable

Comment: In Java you have two kind of input/output objects : the one that lets you read bytes, the ones that lets you read characters. In that language, characters are not bytes, they are translations of bytes (this to support  different language encodings). So, if you want to read byte from a file, then you should use the right classes : InputStream. You have different InputStreams, they only differ by the source of the reading, but basically you can only read bytes from those sources. Once you get an URL, you can get an InputStream to read bytes from the data source the URL represents.

Comment: Now if you want to read bytes from the datasource the URL represents, get the `InputStream is = url.getInputStream();` and then read bytes one by one (for example) with `int i = is.read();` if you are on EOF then i will equals to -1, if not convert the integer to a byte with `byte b = (byte)i;` then you'll have a byte from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the URL as InputStream and use the byte oriented method specifying an array of size equal to 1. Have a look to this page: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)
By the way, use the try-with-resource construct construct when working with streams:

```
byte oneSizeByteArray = new byte[1];
try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
    is.read(oneSizeByteArray,0,1)
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```